# Ruby Rails Calculated attributes used in queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a has_many through association such that a FullApplication has many Districts through FullApplicationDistricts and my applications table has a number of bigit columns for storing currency. I need to track other amounts for each application that are calculations of stored amounts and it seems like creating separate db columns for those and updating each time an application is updated isn't ideal, rather I should create Application class methods for returning the calculated values. However, I need to run queries for the sum of those calculated amounts grouped by district and I'm running into errors like "calculated_value_one" is not a column in the table. My current code:

models:

```
class FullApplication < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fullapplication_districts, inverse_of: :full_application, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :districts, through: :fullapplication_districts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :fullapplication_districts

  def calculated_value_one
    return self.value_one + self.value_two + self.value_three
  end
end

class FullapplicationDistrict < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :full_application
  belongs_to :district

  validates_presence_of :full_application, :district
end

class District < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fullapplication_districts, inverse_of: :district, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :full_applications, through: :fullapplication_districts
end
```

The query I need should return the sum of calculated_value_one grouped by district. I've been trying various queries like the following to no avail.

```
FullApplication.joins(:districts).select("districts.name").distinct.where("full_applications.status_id IN (?)",[1,10]).group("districts.name").sum(:calculated_value_one)
```

From what I've been able to find online it seems like this might not be possible given the fact that the chaining is converted to pure SQL. So from there I explored using attr_accessor like:

```
class FullApplication < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  attr_accessor :calculated_value_one
  after_commit :set_calculated_value_one
```

But I couldn't get that to work either. `FullApplication.find(1).calculated_value_one` was always returning `nil` in the console. Finally I tried creating an actual db column for calculated_value_one and setting its calculated value thusly:

```
class FullApplication < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  after_commit :set_calculated_value_one
  def calculated_value_one
    self.update(calculated_value_one: value_one + self.value_two + self.value_three)
  end
```

But that resulted in `stack level too deep` errors (recursive updates I guess?). At this point I know I just don't know enough Ruby and Rails to know how to properly tackle this requirement. Please help!